# Multiple for-loops from one $result = $conn->query($query)

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli

I have imported data into a table and I am now accessing that data with PHP using the code as follows,

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM JunkData";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if(!$result) die("Fatal Error");

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($name = 0; $name < $rows; ++$name)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . '<br/>';
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();
```

This works!
I am really just curious why adding a second for-loop does not work, unless I declare $result again?

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM JunkData";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if(!$result) die("Fatal Error");

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($name = 0; $name < $rows; ++$name)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . '<br/>';
}

for ($number = 0; $number < $rows; ++$number)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Number']) . 'Flag<br/>';
}


$result->close();
$conn->close();
```

Doesn't work, although 'Flag' is printed an appropriate number of times.
Whereas if I declare $result again.

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM JunkData";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if(!$result) die("Fatal Error");

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($name = 0; $name < $rows; ++$name)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . '<br/>';
}

$result = $conn->query($query);

for ($number = 0; $number < $rows; ++$number)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Number']) . '<br/>';
}


$result->close();
$conn->close();
```

The code does work.
I have tried unsetting a few variables with unset($row) etc and I did notice if I remove the line,

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

from the second for loop, it will print the last value in the Number column as many times as the loop will run.

I hope that is understandable. I am wondering what is happening in the code that I need to re-declare $result if I want to run a second for loop against it.

Comment: Why are you running the same query twice and only getting 1 column each time? You could combine the two loops and just get both columns in the same for loop? You're making it more difficult and more inefficient for yourself than it needs to be

Comment: As @AFriend said, why not put both `echo` in the same `for` loop considering you're using the exact same data?

Comment: I do understand this reasoning and see that the way I am coding here is overly complicated. It was an attempt to try and understand the code, using repetition, which led me to find a problem in the code that I could not see the cause of. I have asked here and was provided with good answers. @Felippe Duarte explained a concept I did not know about and I am grateful for the help I received here. It is true that I will re-write the code myself but I have gained an insight into what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an internal pointer when you call `fetch_*` function.

In your first `for` loop, you send the pointer to the end of the result set.
So, the next `fetch` will return nothing.

If you run `$result->data_seek(0)` you will reset this pointer and can reuse:

```
for ($name = 0; $name < $rows; ++$name)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . '<br/>';
}

$result->data_seek(0); //<---- REPLACE HERE

for ($number = 0; $number < $rows; ++$number)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['Number']) . '<br/>';
}
```

Of course, usually there is no need to loop the same result set twice, you may need to rethink your logic and loop only once.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution I would recommend is to do `fetch_all()`

Instead of:

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($name = 0; $name < $rows; ++$name)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Do

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    ...
}
// then you can re-loop same array of $rows
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to pass MYSQLI_ASSOC to get the results as associative array.

Comment: User Dharman has already added a note similar to mine as a comment. Use "$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);" to get the results as an associative array.

Thank you for your answer, I may do it this way in the future.